# About higher spin gauge theory

Tags: string-theory, holographic-principle, higher-spin

I'm going to listen to a talk about Vasiliev's higher spin gauge theory. Before that I want to know more about the background.[This](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+spin+gauge+theory) is an introduction. Could anybody give a more detailed introduction of this kind of theory? What is the corresponding conserved charge to higher spin particles?

Comment: corresponding to what?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207309/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may begin by reading the reviews on the subject, e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611024 and more detailed http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0503128

What type of charges do you have in mind?

Comment: I already got an answer. The charge conservation (charges corresponding to higher spin fields) are fixed by higher dimension boundary conditions.

Comment: Does not look like an answer to me - do not even understand what is "higher dimension boundary conditions". In principle, analogously to spin-one electric current, spin-two stress-tensor we can construct conserved tensors (in the theory of complex scalar for example) $j_{\mu_1...\mu_s}=\bar{\phi}(x) (\overleftarrow{\partial_\mu}-\overrightarrow{\partial_\mu})^s\phi(x) $ of which spin-one and spin-two are particular cases. These give rise to conserved charges one wish to call higher-spin charges.