# Review of Higher Spin Theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, higher-spin

What is the most comprehensive and up-to-date review of [Higher Spin Theory](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=review&as_epq=higher+spin+theory) (in particular, in AdS space)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends if you are interested in the 2+1 dimensional or the 3+1 dimensional theory.

Under the condition that you mean 3+1 dimensions:

[Nonlinear higher spin theories in various dimensions -
X. Bekaert, S. Cnockaert, Carlo Iazeolla, M.A. Vasiliev](http://inspirehep.net/record/678495)
is a standard reference

[Elements of Vasiliev theory - V.E. Didenko, E.D. Skvortsov](http://inspirehep.net/record/1276863) for an introduction

Additionally there is a whole special issue of "Journal of Physics A" that includes reviews (also for 2+1 dimensional Holography (Gaberdiel and Gopakumar) and 2+1 dimensioanl black holes (Ammon et al)):
https://iopscience.iop.org/1751-8121/46/21